# PHP Nested foreach with XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm pulling info from an xml file using foreach and everthing is fine at the top level. When I try to do a nested foreach to get every instance of children further down I only get the first instance. In this case it's the 'Time' node I'm trying to list but as I've said all I get is:

Movie One
2019-02-10T14:30:00

I want to list all for Movie One.

Here is a sample of the xml.

```
<Events>
<Event>
    <Name>Movie One</Name>
    <Times>
        <EventTime>
        <Time>2019-02-10T14:30:00</Time>
        <Capacity>100</Capacity>
        </EventTime>
    </Times> 
    <Times>
        <EventTime>
        <Time>2019-03-10T18:30:00</Time>
        <Capacity>100</Capacity>
        </EventTime>
    </Times> 
    <Times>
        <EventTime>
        <Time>2019-03-10T18:30:00</Time>
        <Capacity>100</Capacity>
        </EventTime>
    </Times> 
</Event>
</Events>
```

And here is what I'm trying in PHP.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("myfile.xml") or die("Error: Not Working");
foreach($xml->children() as $cinemalist) {
    echo '<p>Event Name: ' . $cinemalist->Name . " </p> ";
      foreach($cinemalist->Times->children() as $alltimes) {
        $showtimes = $alltimes->EventTime->Time;
        echo '<span>' . $showtimes . " </span> ";  
    }
}
?>
```

Fixed: Added 'Times' node to the nested foreach, now works...   foreach($cinemalist->**Times**->children() as $alltimes)

Comment: It works https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/7u

Comment: @splash58 thanks a lot, I'll go back and see if it's just something on my environment, strange.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Added 'Times' node to the nested foreach, now works... foreach($cinemalist->Times->children() as $alltimes)

My initial XML was incorrect that @splash58 used in his correct demo that worked.